# Including markers in google map for flutter based on Json file

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm trying to add marker to my map widget based on the string in a Json file. However i have no idea how the marker thingy works after the .addMarker no longer applied. Can anyone please explain on it?

Answer (score 1):

The `markers:` attribute in the Flutter_Google_maps widget now takes a `Set<Marker>()`.

to add markers, first you should create an empty `Set` of type `Marker` and assign it to the `markers:` attribute in the google maps widget. Consequently, you append the desired `Marker()` to the created set using the `add()` method. Finally, you use `setState()` to rebuild the widget and display the updated Markers set on the UI.

Example:

```
class MapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapsScreenState createState() => _MapsScreenState();
}

class _MapsScreenState extends State<MapsScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapsController = Completer();
  Set<Marker> _myMarkers = Set<Marker>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _myMakers.add(
      markerId: MarkerId("current"),
      position: LatLng(yourLatitude, yourLongitude),
      );
       setState((){});
      )},
    ),
  body: GoogleMap(
    initialCameraPosition: _anyCameraPosition,
    markers: _myMarkers,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _mapsController.complete(controller);
     },
    );
  );

 }
}
```

you have the option to use any state management pattern you prefer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the information. However, my marker is depends on the latlng in the json file and not manually adding, so i think that's the problem.